# Creating selection in select menu discord python

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord, disnake

I want after selecting the first option, for me to have a choice between two other options, like a question within a question. Is it possible to do this?
Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Dropdown(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label='Акрополь', description='Будет отправлен баннер "Акрополь"', emoji='️'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Год Кролика', description='Будет отправлен баннер "Год Кролика"', emoji=''),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Зевс', description='Будет отправлен баннер "Зевс"', emoji='⚡'),
        ]

        super().__init__(placeholder='Выберете ваш любимый цвет...', min_values=1, max_values=1, options=options)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if self.values[0] == 'Акрополь':
            await interaction.response.send_message('Баннер "Акрополь"',file=discord.File(r'C:\Users\Timir\AppData\Local\Discord\Akropol.png'))
        elif self.values[0] == 'Год Кролика':
            await interaction.response.send_message('Баннер "Год Кролика"',file=discord.File(r'C:\Users\Timir\AppData\Local\Discord\Kroll.png'))
        elif self.values[0] == 'Зевс':
            await interaction.response.send_message('Баннер "Зевс"', file=discord.File(r'C:\Users\Timir\AppData\Local\Discord\Zevs.png'))

class DropdownView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(Dropdown())

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('$'), intents=intents)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
        print('------')


intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+', intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def banner(ctx):
    """Отправляет сообщение с выбранным баннером"""

    view = DropdownView()

    await ctx.send('Выберете нужный баннер:', view=view)







@bot.command()
async def Молодец(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} молодец")


bot.run('bottoken')
```

I couldn't find the necessary function and didn't really understand where to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different ways you can do this and it'll depend on what you want to achieve exactly.

If you want a new `Select` with options then you could have a separate `NewSelect` class with your options and callback (similar to your existing one) and then instantiate it when your original select is selected. You can access the parent `View` in the `Select` using `self.view` and then do `self.view.add_item` that way to add a new select to the view. Make sure to update the message with the new view.

*Or*, if you want to modify the options of the existing `Select`, you can change the select's options using `self.options`. And then update the message with the new view.

- [View docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=select#discord.ui.View)
- [Select docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=select#discord.ui.Select)

Hope that gets you in the right direction!